# Install dropbox ends in error

Tags: debian, xfce, dropbox

I'm  trying install dropbox on Debian with xfce and every time it ends with this error

```
bn.BUILD_KEY: Dropbox
bn.VERSION: 3.12.6
bn.DROPBOXEXT_VERSION: failed
bn.is_frozen: True
pid: 11257
ppid: 5898
ppid exe: '/bin/bash'
uid: 1000
user_info: pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='honzik', pw_passwd='x', pw_uid=1000, pw_gid=1000, pw_gecos='Jan Schramhauser,,,', pw_dir='/home/honzik', pw_shell='/bin/bash')
effective_user_info: pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='honzik', pw_passwd='x', pw_uid=1000, pw_gid=1000, pw_gecos='Jan Schramhauser,,,', pw_dir='/home/honzik', pw_shell='/bin/bash')
euid: 1000
gid: 1000
egid: 1000
group_info: grp.struct_group(gr_name='honzik', gr_passwd='x', gr_gid=1000, gr_mem=[])
effective_group_info: grp.struct_group(gr_name='honzik', gr_passwd='x', gr_gid=1000, gr_mem=[])
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: None
cwd: '/home/honzik/.dropbox-dist'
     real_path='/home/honzik/.dropbox-dist'
            mode=040755 uid=1000    gid=1000
     parent mode=040755 uid=1000    gid=1000
HOME: u'/home/honzik'
appdata: u'/home/honzik/.dropbox/instance1'
         real_path=u'/home/honzik/.dropbox/instance1'
                mode=040700 uid=1000    gid=1000
         parent mode=040700 uid=1000    gid=1000
dropbox_path: u'/home/honzik/Dropbox'
              real_path=u'/home/honzik/Dropbox'
                        mode=040777 uid=1000    gid=1000
              parent    mode=040755 uid=1000    gid=1000
sys_executable: '/home/honzik/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-3.12.6/dropbox'
                real_path='/home/honzik/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-3.12.6/dropbox'
                        mode=0100755    uid=1000    gid=1000
                parent  mode=040755 uid=1000    gid=1000
trace.__file__: '/home/honzik/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-3.12.6/library.zip/dropbox/client/ui/common/boot_error.pyc'
                real_path='/home/honzik/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-3.12.6/library.zip/dropbox/client/ui/common/boot_error.pyc'
                        not found
                parent  not found
tempdir: '/tmp'
         real_path='/tmp'
                mode=041777 uid=0   gid=0
         parent mode=040755 uid=0   gid=0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dropbox/client/main.py", line 4065, in main_startup
  File "dropbox/client/main.py", line 1980, in run
  File "ui/common/uikit.py", line 383, in create_ui_kit
  File "dropbox/client/ui/qt/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
  File "dropbox/client/ui/qt/setup_wizard.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "dropbox/client/ui/qt/xui.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "PyQt5/QtWebKit.py", line 14, in <module>
ImportError: libxslt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Earlier I used gnome and Dropbox worked flawlessly. Does somebody know, what is missing? I don't understand this error. I did it according to instructions on Dropbox website.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libxslt1.1` and reinstalling should solve your problem

Comment: good, answer posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message the OP posted shows libxslt.so.1 is missing, as in "libxslt.so.1: cannot open shared object file"

Using debian.packages.org or a system where this library is present shows the name of the package:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1
libxslt1.1:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1
```

Knowing the name of package is lixslt1.1, the command to install it is:

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt1.1
```

After installing the XSLT library, it should be then enough to try again to install DropBox.

Comment: also works on ubuntu 16.04.01

Answer (score 2):

Just a side note for those who face the same problem on a headless server, or if you just want to run the daemon without the interface.

If you `unset DISPLAY` (or set it to nothing as in: `export DISPLAY=""`), the problem will go away.

I had this problem on a headless Debian Wheezy. If you try to get all dependencies, you will end up with a desktop server.

Unsetting DISPLAY will probably be very bad for a desktop install though. But even in my headless config, I wanted to keep the DISPLAY variable set (for remote X windows). The solution I found was to define DISPLAY="" when calling the daemon, as in:

`DISPLAY="" /path/to/dropoboxd`

Works fine for me.

"Funny" fact is that adding a new account with this broken configuration renders a permissions error http link, instead of the computer's http link (which may cause people like me to look in the wrong direction for hours). The daemon log looks exactly like yours.

Reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Error-messages/Headless-ubuntu-dropbox-3-12-6-broken/td-p/164223